# Using node js to extract dates out of a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to create a discord happy birthday bot.

So say if a user says "My birthday is 5/20/1980"
Then it will log the Date, and on that specific date send a message in the discord channel telling them Happy Birthday.

Is the current code I have which only sends a message in the discord channel
whenever the message is exactly "my birthday is"

app.js

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    console.log(`${message.author.tag} Message Sent`);
    if (message.content === 'my birthday is') {
        message.channel.send('Will remember your birthday buddy!')
    }
})
```

Also, would it be better to save the date in a DB, or like say in Json if possible.

Comment: What exactly the question? Are looking for a way to extract the date from a string? Then use regex for that or you took the date and want to save the date somewhere?

Comment: The problem here is that there are numerous formats and ways to write a date. That would be a very complex regex solution.

Comment: Have a look at moment.js. Might help you out

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara Yes basically. The user will send a message with their birthday, and I want to extract the date from the message they send.

Comment: @Aleks right, okay I will take a look at moment.js. Thank you!